# .click function only works with breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`enter code here`I have a clickover box, and inside this box I have a button.  WHen the popover isShown, I setthe .click function through javascript.  The click function only gets called when I put a breakpoint on the

```
$("#button").click(function (event)
```

http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

```
    $('.socialMediaEnabled .btn-palette-checkbox-unchecked').clickover(
    {
        //      auto_close: 3 * 1000,
        width: 170, height: 80,
        placement: 'right',
        onShown: function () {  button.init(); }
    })


var button= function (credentials, url) 
{
    this.init = function () 
    {
        //facebook
        $("#button").attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
        $("#button").click(function (event) 
        {


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you put it in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Could we possibly see more than half a line of your code?

Comment: Can you give us a more full example of your code?

Comment: How do you verify that the handler is only bound with the breakpoint (which I doubt btw)? If your click event handler has an error or it has no noticeable impact on the application's state, then simply clicking the button is not enough to test whether the handler is bound or not.

Comment: You'll find it a lot easier to see errors if you use correct tabbing/formatting...

Answer (score 1):

When I ran that code, I was getting an error stating that init was not a valid function.

Try using a new on the button object:

```
var button = new function() {
    this.init= function() {
        //facebook
        $("#button").attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
        $("#button").click(function(event) {
             alert('a');
        });
    }
}​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/XWbfV/19/

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo left over from the inside of init